# Opposite of "against someone's will" in this context

Tags: word-request, spoken-english

He sold their house **against his father's will.**

I'm quite confused as to as what is the opposite of **against someone's will** in this context.

Is it **with someone's consent?**

Please tell me the most natural way to express this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've got it..

Comment: Assuming you don't mean *last will and testament* ?

Comment: "with [someone]'s consent" implies that [someone] gave permission for something to happen. You could take it one step further and say "with [someone]'s approval", which means that [someone] is actually in favour of what happened.

Comment: Yes, with someone's consent is the opposite.

Comment: "opposite" can mean different things. Is the opposite of "tall" "short" or the weaker "not tall"? Likewise do you mean without anyone objecting, or with someone's approval or enthusiastic agreement.

Answer (score 0):

You have found a very good one yourself but...

There is the question what does 'will' mean. He did it although his dad said 'no'. Or he did it breaking the terms of his dad's will (document). In the latter case, you will probably be inclined to preseve the reference of the document instead of hiding it in the term 'consent'. In that case:

- in accordance with someone's will
- according to someone's will
- in agreement with someone's will
- in compliance with someone's will
- following someone's will
- ...

Comment: according to someone's will does not work here. Think about that.

Comment: I think mostly you'd say "...wishes" not "...will" in these examples.

Comment: @lambie "according to" would work if the OP is talking about someone's last will and testament. It's not clear if that is what is meant here though.